# Ключевое слово self

Tags: python-3.x

1. Питоновский `self` - это аналог `this` Явы?
2. Питоновский метод `init` - аналог конструктора Явы?

Comment: Нет и нет, потому что зависит от контекста, а вы контекст не указали. И это не ключевые слова

Comment: Ну почему? Это действительно аналоги, просто свойства у них совпадают не на 100%

Comment: @Dims какой-нибудь `self = 5` и близко не аналог this :) (Да, я зануда)

Comment: Язык же другой сильно. Вот и отличие: в Java к this вообще присваивать нельзя.

Comment: Конструктор в питоне это `__init__`, а не `init` :) И да, self это по сути this. Вообще, self это принятое название первого параметра метода объекта класса, в который передается ссылка на объект класса и он может называться как угодно, хоть `this` :) А вот для статичных методов и методов класса не передается ссылка на объект класса (т.е. `self`), да и не может ее быть -- объект ведь в этом случаи и не создается. Немного топорно объяснил, но думаю в целом понятно

Answer (score 1):

`self` не является ключевым словом в Питоне:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword('self')
False
>>> keyword.kwlist
['False', 'None', 'True', 'and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'nonlocal', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

При вызове метода, объект передаётся в качестве первого аргумента. По соглашению, первый аргумент у методов называется self. В этом смысле, поверхностно, self внутри методов используется похоже на this в Java. self является обычным идентификатором, к примеру, [`self = None` иногда полезен](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22245002/4279).

Пример:

```
class Class:
    def method(self, arg):
        print(arg)

obj = Class()
obj.method(1)
# в этом случае это эквивалентно
Class.method(obj, 1)
```

---

`__init__` не является конструктором. `__new__` создаёт сами объекты, когда класс вызывается. `__init__` это инициализатор, который обычно вызывается после `__new__`.

`__init__` специальный метод принимает `self` параметр, поэтому объект уже создан к тому времени когда `__init__` вызывается. Обычно `__init__` используется, чтобы атрибуты объекта определить—по соглашению новые атрибуты не следует вне `__init__` создавать.

Comment: Вообще-то уточнение про специальный метод, который принимает уже созданный объект, справедливо для конструктора в **любом** языке. Не вижу причин, по которым `__init__` отличался бы от конструктора.

Comment: @PavelMayorov чтобы понять в чём у вас заблуждение, подумайте как создаются и инициализируются *неизменяемые* объекты в Питоне.

Comment: Это вы к чему?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov: подумайте: 1- есть ли у неизменяемых объектов конструкторы? (подсказка: *есть*) 2- что `__init__()` для неизменяемых объектов делает? (подсказка: *ничего*)

Comment: а вы подумайте еще раз, можно ли метод, который ничего не делает называть инициализатором. И перестаньте придираться к словам и деталям реализации.

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы написали: *"Не вижу причин, по которым `__init__` отличался бы от конструктора."* я попытался вам намекнуть на возможные причины (это не атака на вас. Практика показывает, что если человек сам часть пути пройдёт и самостоятельно выводы сделает, то знание лучше усваивается. Так как это не ответ, а комментарий, направленный на одного человека, то эта техника обучения мне показалась подходящей).