# Создание уникальных объектов в Python

Tags: python

Как в Python подменить в конструкторе текущий объект на другой ?

```
registry = {}
class Data:
    def __init__(self,V):
        # поиск готового объекта в реестре
        if V in registry: self = registry[V] # возвращаем найденный
        else: # создаем новый
            self.val = V
            registry[V] = self # регистрируем созданный объект
```

Answer (score 4):

`__init__` метод инициализирует уже созданный новый объект, переданный как self параметр. См. [Ключевое слово self](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612564/23044).

Чтобы повторно использовать старый объект, определите `__new__` метод, который ответственен за создание новых объектов.  Вот [пример кода для Byte класса](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2980871/4279), где одинаковые байты представлены одним и тем же объектом.